# Scipy LPF ValueError : could not convert b, a, and x to a common type

Tags: python, scipy, pytorch, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I'm trying to remove noise from signal - which is decoded by my own network.
I trained network and process signal in python, so I tried scipy.signal module to customize lowpass filter.
There are few examples about the module and codes are very simple. But when I put my signal to this filter, it gives value error.

Code :

```
def lowPass_Filter(signal, cutoff, fs, order):

    sig = signal
    norm_cutoff = cutoff / (0.5 * fs)
    b, a = butter(order, norm_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    sig = lfilter(b, a, sig)
    signal = sig

return signal

signal = lowPass_Filter(input_signal, 0.3, float(s_hz), 77)
```

Error :

```
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 2030, in lfilter
return sigtools._linear_filter(b, a, x, axis)
ValueError: could not convert b, a, and x to a common type
```

I searched for the remedy but couldn't find proper case with 'common type' message. Someone said that zero dimension of the signal may caused the error, but the signal I use shows intended shape.

I tried different cutoff and order to make it work. And I have no idea to try anymore.

Any opinion must be very helpful to me. If you can see any issue, please give me advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of a, b, or x is a scalar with shape of `()`